# How to represent "somewhere to the left" in prolog?

Tags: prolog, rule, dcg

In the Prolog, how to represent the situation "somewhere to the left".
For example, there is a List "List" and two terms "X" and "Y", how to represent the rule: X is somewhere to the left of Y in the List.

Comment: Or you could ask your CSCI460 TA (me) for help.  Please do your own work.

Comment: Oh, excuse me, could you tell me whether I violate the rule of the course when I ask for help like this in stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be reduced to the problem of subsequence matching.

```
subsequence([], _).
subsequence([X|Sub], [X|Seq]) :-
    subsequence(Sub, Seq).
subsequence(Sub, [_|Seq]) :-
    subsequence(Sub, Seq).
```

Then your "left-of" query would be `subsequence([X, Y], List), !`.

Comment: @user918304: if you'd have tried this solution, you'd have found out that it works the way you want; no need for `Y` to immediately follow `X`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to describe some properties of lists.  Grammars are often the best way to address this.

```
... --> [].
... --> [_], ... .

?- Xs = "abc", phrase((...,[X], ..., [Y], ...), Xs).
   Xs = "abc", X = a, Y = b
;  Xs = "abc", X = a, Y = c
;  Xs = "abc", X = b, Y = c
;  false.
```

Answer (score 1):

it can be done in many ways.
nth1(N,List,X) is a predicate that is true if the Nth element of the List is X.

The implementation using nth1 is pretty easy; try to solve it before you see my code.

```
left(X,Y,L):-
    nth1(NX,L,X),
    nth1(NY,L,Y),
    NX<NY.
```

Other ways to solve it is with append/3:

```
left(X,Y,L):-
   append(_,[X|T],L),
   member(Y,L).
```

or just plain recursion:

```
left(X,Y,[X|T]):-
   member(Y,T).
left(X,Y,[H|T]):-
   H=\=X,
   left(X,Y,T).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the append/3 predicate then you can use:

```
left(A,B,S) :-
    append(_,[B,A|_],S).
```

If you ask:

```
?- left(1,2,[1,2,3,4]).
false.

?- left(2,1,[1,2,3,4]).
true
```

-Leo